How can I get collision working with tiles
I have two tiles FRects that I need collision to be checked but because both are from different map vectors. I can't check them inside a for loop together, as this will not work and will slow down my game
for (size_t row = 0; row < map.size(); ++row) {
    for(size_t col = 0; col < map[row].size(); ++col) {
       size_t index = row * map[0].size_t + col;

       for (size_t row2 = 0; < map2.size(); ++row2) {
           for(size_tcol2=0;col2<map2[row2].size();++col2{
               size_t index2 = row2 * map2[0] map2.size() + col2;

               if (map[row][col] == 37) {       
                  if(map2[row2[col2]62{
m_AABBCollision.handleCollsionY(nullptr,&m_Mushroom,&tileFRects2[index2],&[tileFRects[index]);
m_Mushroom.updatePositionY(&tileFRects2[index2];
                  }
                }
           }
        }
    }
}

This is how far I made it but it's really slow and when checking more
tiles I don't even know if it's the framerate or code.

"because both are from different map vectors. I can't check them inside a for loop together" - Why not? They are still the same spot in the world, right? You don't need to check map[0][0] with map2[30][30], right? Just use the smaller of the sizes in the for loop and calculate the index values separately.
